# How to create extension methods for Types

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I am writing an extension method for parsing JSON string for any given type. I wanted to use the method on types instead of instances like many examples we already know, but I somewhat feel it is not supported by Visual Studio. Can someone enlighten me here? The following is the method:

```
public static T ParseJson<T>(this T t, string str) where T: Type
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) return null;
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var obj = serializer.Deserialize<T>(str);
    return obj;
}
```

I want to call the method in this fashion:

```
var instance = MyClass.ParseJson(text);
```

Thanks

Comment: Note that `ParseJson` returns a `Type` not a `MyClass` with this definition.

Comment: Thanks for the catch. I actually tried var instance = typeof(MyClass).ParseJson(text); not working

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The short answer is it cannot be done; extension methods need to work on an instance of something.

Answer (score 9):

To use the extension method, you would have to do:

```
var instance = typeof(MyClass).ParseJson(text);
```

The token "MyClass" is not a Type instamce intself, but using typeof will get you a Type to operate on.  But how is this any better than:

```
var instance = JsonUtility.ParseJson<MyClass>(text);
```

Edit: Actually, the code for the extension method still would not do what you wanted.  It will always return a "Type" object, not an instance of that Type.

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the accepted answer, you can't. However, provided that you have an extension method that can be called from an instance of T:

```
public static T ParseJson<T>(this T t, string s)
```

You could write a utility method like this:

```
public static T ParseJson<T>(string s)
    where T: new()
    => new(T).ParseJson(s);
```

And call it like this:

```
var t = Utilities.ParseJson<T>(s);
```

I am afraid that's the best you can do...

Answer (score 2):

You can't create extension methods that apply to the type itself. They can only be called on instances of a type.

Comment: and null instances of that type which is one of the redeeming values of ext. methods :)  string val = null; val.IsNullOrEmpty()
Sweet...

Answer (score -1):

You can create and extension method

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static string Serialize<T>(this T self)
    {
        return JsonSerializer.Serialize(self);
    }
}
```

And use it like

```
instance.Serialize();
```

You don't have to use it like `instance.Serialize<Type>();` because most of the time (if not all the time) it can be inferred from the usage.

Comment: do you realize the op has an extension method but he wants to instantiate an object from an extension method on the type not on the instance.