# How to Extend the Type Class

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

this is my code:

```
bool ch=Type.IsBuiltIn("System.Int32");   // not working-> syntax error


public static class MyExtentions
    {             
        public static bool IsBuiltIn(this Type t, string _type)
        {
            return (Type.GetType(_type) == null) ? false : true;
        }
    }
```

Please I want Extend Type Class by IsBuiltIn new method

Comment: You don't need extension method here

Comment: write `typeof(int).IsBuiltIn` to your editor. What do you see?

Comment: the string you pass to the IsBuiltIn() method should be assembly-qualified name of the type. I mean you should pass System.Int32 insted of just int

Comment: "int" just isn't a built-in type.  It is an *alias* that's specific to the C# compiler.  Other languages use other aliases, like "Integer" in VB.NET.  Given that there just a handful of aliases (don't forget the nullable ones), you can hardcode their names.  Or just not do this.

Comment: When does the `IsBuiltIn` return false?

Comment: A method such as `IsBuiltIn` doesn’t really make sense in an extensible type system. What do you need this for? Also, writing `someCondition ? false : true` makes no sense. Just write `!someCondition`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't have static extension methods. Your extension method works on an *instance* of the `Type` class, so to call it you'd have to do something like this:

```
typeof(Type).IsBuiltIn("System.Int32")
```

The workaround for this is to just put your extension method in a utility class, e.g. like the following, and call it like a normal static function:

```
public static class TypeExt
{             
    public static bool IsBuiltIn(string _type)
    {
        return Type.GetType(_type) == null;
    }
}

// To call it:
TypeExt.IsBuiltIn("System.Int32")
```

By the way, I don't think this will tell you whether the type is "built-in"; it will merely tell you whether a type with the given name has been loaded into the process.

Answer (score 3):

Extension methods are intended to describe new APIs on *instances*, not types. In your case, that API would be something like:

```
Type someType = typeof(string); // for example
bool isBuiltIn = someType.IsBuiltIn("Some.Other.Type");
```

which... clearly isn't what you wanted; the `type` here adds nothing and is not related to the `IsBuiltIn`. There is no compiler trick for adding new *static* methods to existing types, basically - so you will not be able to use `Type.IsBuiltIn("Some.Other.Type")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't extend the `Type` class. You need an instance of the class to create an extension method.

Edit:
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848411/how-to-create-extension-methods-for-types) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249222/can-i-add-extension-methods-to-an-existing-static-class).

Comment: Why?? why can't you do so?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel No, you need an instance of a class type. You cannot extent the class type itself.

Comment: When I downvote your answer was only this `You can't extend the Type class` Is that makes sense?

Comment: You can of course write extension methods for `Type`. For ex `"".GetType().IsBuiltIn("")` would work (Although I don't see a good reason to do so).

Comment: I was editing my answer. And now you can find two links that explain it why you can't do it.

Comment: @Maarten When I downvote this was the answer `You can't extend the Type class` Is that makes sense?